# Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 6

Tags: preg-match

I would like to parse the following DocBlock / comment with regex. Code below

```
$subject = <<<HTML
/**
Theme Name: Hello world
*/
HTML;

$pattern = '/^\/(?:*)+Theme Name:(\s)?([\w]+)/';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Running the code output the following error..

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\test.php on line 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` in the `(?:*)` means 0 or more times.

Do you mean `\*`?

https://www.regex101.com/r/vH7lB3/1

Note that I also added `\s*` before `Theme` to match the new line character and spaces

Comment: worked like charm.

Can you please break down the Regex `^\/(?:\*)+\s*Theme Name:(\s)?([\w ]+)` for me to understand? please

Comment: Figured it out.. Thank you @tony-wong